# Why doesn't gradle build fail when there's a compilation error in code

Tags: java, gradle, compiler-errors, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

Let's say I have a Java+Gradle project. And somewhere in one of its classes there's a compilation error.

When I run

```
gradle assemble
```

or

```
gradle compileJava
```

the build turns out to be successful.

Why does it work this way and is it possible to configure gradle to fail in such situations?

Comment: Do you have a concrete example where this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed a command that would compile test classes without running tests and the solution was `gradle compileTestJava`

Answer (score 1):

This can happen the compilation error is in the test sources - neither `assemble` nor `compileJava` compile (and run) the tests.

The solution is to run `gradle build` (which runs `assemble` and `check`)